# Doubts in MVVM implementation

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

This is the architecture I have implemented.

[image]

Basically I want to select "cells" in View 2 and "locations" will be populated from the selected cell. Then I have combo box with "systems" and I want upon system selection, to populate different set of cells. For that I am using IOC to access different view-model.

Doubt is that whether I have implemented according to MVVM pattern. The part with `UpdateModel` looks not so nice to me. I would appreciate if somebody could review architecture and tell me what I could have done better. Also is it right to have model instances in view-model or I should use data service pattern, like in mvvm-light boilerplate?

Question: can I implement response to system change without calling UpdateModel function but using mvvm-light's native mechanisms to update ViewModel2?

Below some key parts of the code.

ViewModel2:

```
    public List<string> LocationList
    {
        get
        {
            var cells = _wList.GetCells(currentSystemNumber);
            var cell = cells[_selectedCellItem.Key];
            return cell.Locations;
        }
    }

    private KeyValuePair<int, string> _selectedCellItem;
    public KeyValuePair<int, string> SelectedCellItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedCellItem;
        }

        set
        {
            Set(ref _selectedCellItem, value);
            RaisePropertyChanged("LocationList");
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<int, string>> CellList
    {
        get
        {
            int count = _wList.GetCells(currentSystemNumber).Count;
            ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<int, string>> cells = new ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();
            for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                cells.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(i, string.Format("Cell {0}/{1}", i, currentSystemNumber+1)));
            return cells;
        }
    }

    public void UpdateModel(int system)
    {
        currentSystemNumber = system;

        RaisePropertyChanged("CellList");
        RaisePropertyChanged("LocationList");
    }
```

View2:

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox x:Name="listBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="104" Margin="121,32,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="144" ItemsSource="{Binding LocationList}"/>
    <ListBox x:Name="listBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="104" Margin="10,32,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="102" ItemsSource="{Binding CellList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCellItem}" DisplayMemberPath="Value"/>
    <Label x:Name="label" Content="Cells" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,1,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label x:Name="label1" Content="Locations" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="121,1,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Grid>
```

ViewModel1:

```
    private ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<int, string>> _systems = new ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();
    public ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<int, string>> Systems
    {
        get
        {
            return _systems;
        }
    }

    private KeyValuePair<int, string> _selectedSystemItem;
    public KeyValuePair<int, string> SelectedSystemItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedSystemItem;
        }
        set
        {
            Set(ref _selectedSystemItem, value);
            var locator = (ViewModelLocator)Application.Current.Resources["Locator"];
            var vm = locator.DASrvPageVM;
            vm.UpdateModel(value.Key);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Changing `KeyValuePair` to `Tuple` solved the issue. Only thing remained is to make sure my architecture doesn't have stinky places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial answer here to address some code smells and doubts you have with your architecture:

1. ViewModels shouldn't know about other ViewModels so ViewModel1 shouldn't call into ViewModel2.
2. ServiceLocator shouldn't be used if at all possible. ViewModelLocator should only be used by the framework and not called directly. If you fix issue 1, that will remove this issue as well.
3. Models can implement INotifyPropertyChanged as well as the ViewModels. This way you could put properties for SelectedSystem, SelectedCell, and SelectedLocation on a model and have those fire the PropertyChanged event.
4. Use your ViewModel to pull your Models out of some type of repository. This way the state of the Model is persisted when the ViewModels update their properties. ViewModels may or may not keep state based on how the ViewModelLocator is working internally. Use Models and/or Repositories to ensure the state lasts beyond the life of the ViewModel.
5. Use ObservableCollections for nearly all collection types in ViewModels and Models so the Views can bind to these without having to perform so much logic on the getters. Rule of thumb, if you want to see any value or collection on the View, make sure they are Observable. This will allow the full power of MVVM bindings to be used and removes tons of boilerplate code trying to keep the View updated.

Comment: Thanks for observations. That pretty much confirmed my doubts. So should I directly specify in XAML binding objects from model? I was thinking model shouldn't directly interact with view.

Comment: Models don't interact with the view, but they can and should implement INotifyPropertyChanged. They just notify listeners of the change. The View is bound to the ViewModel which can have the Model as a property. This way the binding will look like `Text="{Binding Model.Name}"`. The ViewModel should still do all the interaction with the Model and the View simply subscribes to those changes via the Binding syntax.

Comment: just one more thing... if I instanciate my model in ViewModel2, then I still need to access it from ViewModel1, as one of the UI components is located there. Does it make sence to use singletone pattern(IOC for example) to obtain Model instance in ViewModel2 or there is a better way?

Comment: Yes, there is a better way. Look into IoC (inversion of control). For WPF, there is Unity (not the game engine) or SimpleInjector that I have used. It's a steep learning curve, but amazing once it all clicks. Basically you would have an object that was maintaining state like a ISession object that has your Model as a property. Then VM1 and VM2 would both take an ISession in the constructor. Then they could both manipulate the Model as needed. It would behave like a Singleton, but keep it loosely coupled and testable since ISession is just an interface you can mock it.

Comment: I wouldn't use a singleton directly in the VM's. I would use IoC for sure just to keep loosely coupled. You may want to look into Prism as well. It's like MVVM-light on steroids. Prism has some great documentation and white papers on application architecture. It's made by MS guys so it's cool to see how WPF is used by the creators of the framework.